# When Subtracting Dates I get a Date Number in Excel

Tags: excel, date

I'm subtracting two dates in Excel but instead of number of days, I'm getting a date but in number format. It was working but it's now outputting "4,3832".

[image]

Comment: You need to format the cell as date to show output result. Otherwise you can use `TEXT()` function to your required format.

Comment: Did you check the two dates you are performing the operation on? Try using the evaluate formula (under formulas tab) to evaluate the formula step by step and see if there's a value that you don't expect in one of the intermediate steps. It seems that one of the dates you are working with is blank, i.e. returns 0.